# Discord js voice connection subscribe not detecting end event

Tags: discord.js

```
let audioStream = connection.receiver.subscribe(message.member.user.id)
 audioStream.on('data' , (chunk) => {
   console.log(chunk)
 })
 connection.receiver.speaking.on('end', () => {
     console.log("ended")
 })
```

Why does it not detect the end event?

Comment: Does your bot have the voice states intent on in the Discord developer settings?